# Driver hp raid controller b120i

Tags: server, hp, raid

I have a problem with a installation of ubuntu 12.04 server on HP SL4540 with raid controller b120i.
Ubuntu during installation does not recognize the raid controller, and displays the disk separately.
Can you tell me how to recognize the controller?

Daniel

Comment: If the Operating System can see the disks separetely, it means you didn't create a RAID volume on the RAID controller.

Comment: There is discussion about this here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/214703 You can post there your problem.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 12.04 doesn't support b110i/b120i/b320i raid controller yet.

http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/ubuntu/exceptions/ubuntu-exceptions.html

Answer (score 0):

In the link I pasted above (for launchpad thread) guy from HP said those controllers are in fact software raid... and he only encourages use of HP driver (once it will be publicly released in binary only form) if you want to upgrade to a 'real' controller... He adivised to use linux software raid otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add the link you refer to in your answer :)